# How does Entity Framework handle connections when using SqlQuery<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ninject

Will Entity Framework dispose the SqlConnection used in the GetFooFromUnmappableEntity method?

I have the following service:

```
public class FooService {
    private readonly FooContext fooContext;

    public FooService(FooContext fooContext) {
        this.fooContext = fooContext;
    }

    public Foo GetFooFromUnmappableEntity(int id) {
        return fooContext.Database.SqlQuery<Foo>(string.Format("select * from GetFoo({0})", id);
    }
}
```

I'm using Ninject to manage my dependencies in a *class library*. So A binding exists somewhere like this:

```
Bind<FooContext>.ToSelf();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ninject is an implementation of "dependency inversion", which means your dependencies are interfaces and Ninject will give you the implementations. You will want to create a `IFooRepository` that in its implementation uses `FooContext`. then `IFooRepository` gets injected into the constructor of `IFooService` and `IFooService` doesn't need to know anything about how the repository is implemented.

As far as disposing the SqlConnection, you will want to bind your repository `.InRequestScope()` and use the `OnePerRequestModule` [which will dispose your objects at the end of the request.](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope)

Comment: I can't use InRequestScope because, as I said, these bindings occur in a class library, not an asp.net project.